# Date Difference (3 Columns)

Tags: 2010, column

I have a problem in SharePoint 2010. I have a list with three columns:

- Date Notified
- Packet Mailed
- Condolence Letter Sent

The problem is that `Packet Mailed` or `Condolence Letter Sent` could be empty, so this new column should be empty as well, if that's the case. The formula I used has errors, and I can not find another one. Could you help me?

I am able to make two column formula work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Packet Mailed]),"",[Packet Mailed]-[Date Notified])
```

Here is the formula that i am getting an error with:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Packet Mailed],[Condolence Letter Sent]),"",([Packet Mailed],[Condolence Letter Sent])-[Date Notified]))
```

Here is the Columns i need to formulate:

- Packet Mailed
- Condolence Letter Sent
- Date Notified

Thank You,
Arron

Answer (score 0):

Arron,

If I got you correct, following formula should work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Packet Mailed]), "", IF(ISBLANK([Condolence Letter Sent]), "", [Condolence Letter Sent])-[Date Notified]))
```

And for ease you can use Microsoft Excel to prepare formula for Calculate Fields, as they use same formula's as of EXCEL!

I hope this helps...